# Angular animation has effect of jumping through different heights of content

Tags: css, angular, animation

Wants to create an animation in angular which will be called with a change in routing. The animation is called on the div that contains the outlet. The animation itself works quite well, there is only a problem on mobile devices, due to the fact that the components have different heights there is a jumping effect when changing and I have no idea how to solve this, if someone had a similar problem I would be happy to know the solution. Below is the code I am using

```
<div class="container">
<header class="header">
</header>

<div class="outlet" [@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)">
    <router-outlet #outlet="outlet">
    </router-outlet>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
</footer>
```

css

```
    .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    
    .header {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .outlet {
        flex: 1;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .footer {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 52px;
    }

}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .container {
        
        .footer {
            margin-left: 6px;
        }
    }
}
```

ts

```
 export class AuthOutletComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private loaderScreenService: LoaderScreenService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loaderScreenService.hide();
  }

  prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData;
  }

}
```

animation

```
    export const authRouteAnimations =
  trigger('routeAnimations', [
    transition('* <=> *', authFadeInFadeOut()),
  ]);

function authFadeInFadeOut() {
  const optional = { optional: true };

  return [
    query(':enter, :leave', [
      style({
        position: 'absolute',
        pop: 0,
        left:0,
        width: '100%',
        height: 'auto',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      })
    ], optional),
    query(':enter', [
      style({opacity: 0 })
    ], optional),
    query(':leave', [
      style({ left: 0, opacity: 1 })
    ], optional),
    group([
      query(':leave', [
        animate('800ms ease', style({ left: '+30%', opacity: 0 }))
      ], optional),
      query(':enter', [
        animate('800ms 550ms ease', style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ], optional)
    ]),
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, the problem is that the old content of the previous page is still when visiting the a new page.

So I fixed it by setting the leave duration of the animation to 0. This way, the old content is already gone before the new page is loaded.

Here is my animation for my pages:

```
export const routeAnimationsState = trigger('routeAnimationTrigger', [
transition(':enter', [
    style({ 
        opacity: 0 
    }), 
    animate(1000),
]),
transition(':leave', [
    animate(0, style({ 
        opacity: 0 
    })),
]),]);
```